# How to concat two CSV files using Pandas when there is no common column

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 CSV files.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Employee': ['ABC', 'XYZ', 'DEF', 'KLM'], 
                   'Age': [25, 32, 38, 40]})
```

```
  Employee  Age
0      ABC   25
1      XYZ   32
2      DEF   38
3      KLM   40
```

---

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Dept': ['IT']})
```

```
  Dept
0   IT
```

When i try to do concat using pandas using the following code,

```
df1=pd.read_csv("file_A")

df2=pd.read_csv("file_B")

pd.concat([df2,df1])
```

I am getting below result :

[image]

But this is what am expecting :

[image]

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't post your dataframe as images, but rather text. I've edited the post to show you how to do it, please follow this pattern in new posts :)

Comment: What happens if df2 have more than one value?

Comment: df2 has only one value and i need to copy the same to all rows in df1

Answer (score 2):

To be honest it's not clear to me why you would be storing a single row of data in a CSV file. I'm giving this answer under a couple of assumptions:

1. You don't have control over how the data is stored.
2. There will only ever be 1 row of data in the second CSV, as you indicated above.

Given those assumptions, `pd.concat` is not really the right tool for this job. If `df2` always has only a single row, you're better off using simple assignment rather than trying to concatenate.

If you've got a single column with a single row, this would work:

```py
df1['Dept'] = df2['Dept'].iloc[0]
```

If you have multiple columns but only a single row, you can do this in a loop:

```py
for column in df2.columns:
    df1[column] = df2[column].iloc[0]
```